# Nginx map client certificate to REMOTE_USER for uWSGI with fallback to basic auth?

Tags: ssl, nginx, mercurial, cgi, uwsgi

I'm using Nginx with uWSGI to serve Mercurial; it does basic auth over SSL (Nginx is the SSL terminator; it doesn't get passed on to Hg), but due to the limited security of basic auth even over SSL, as discussed at various places including this site, I want to allow users to connect with client certificates as well, something that TortoiseHg for example supports.

```
ssl_verify_client optional;
...
map $ssl_client_s_dn $ssl_client_s_dn_cn
{
    default "";
    ~/CN=(?<CN>[^/]+) $CN;
};
...
location /
{
    uwsgi_pass unix:/run/uwsgi/app/hgweb/socket;
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_param SERVER_ADDR $server_addr;
    uwsgi_param REMOTE_USER $ssl_client_s_dn_cn;
    #uwsgi_param REMOTE_USER $remote_user;
    #auth_basic "Mercurial repositories";
    #auth_basic_user_file /srv/hg/.htpasswd;
```

}

So I treat the CN as a username.
But how do I make it fallback to basic auth when there's no client certificate (and preferably *not* when there is a certificate but its verification fails -- just error in that case)? An example I found does it by having a separate server block listening on another port, which I want to avoid: https://github.com/winne27/nginx-cert-and-basic-auth/blob/master/nginx-example.conf

Additionally, in some examples I've seen the following checks in `location`; are they necessary? `if ($ssl_client_verify != SUCCESS) { return 496; }` `if ($ssl_client_s_dn_cn !~ "^[a-z0-9]{1,10}$") { return 496; }` Given http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil I thought it best to avoid using `if`.

Comment: To clarify, my concern with proxy_pass to another server block, as in the linked example, is efficiency. Is that concern misplaced? Does nginx use some optimization when proxying to itself? Also, in that example, it looks like SSL is processed both by the 443 and the failover server block. Is the latter necessary? Would not http://127.0.0.1:80 be more efficient, without affecting security given the proxying is internal to the host?

Comment: Hmmm, I understand now what you need now, and indeed you'd need to handle that in a proxy/sub request or at your application (validating the remote user and password in your application code). Still, the `if`s should be avoided. And if you're going to add this to your server block: `if ($ssl_client_verify != SUCCESS) { return 496; }` consider using `ssl_verify_client on;` instead of optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two possible solutions, you can either overwrite the `uwsgi_param` or use `$remote_user` a default value for the variable `$ssl_client_s_dn_cn`.

---

To overwrite the `uwsgi_param` (this should also work with `fastcgi_param`), use the `map` directive as you suggested (just remove the ";" after "}"), and use the `if_not_empty` parameter for the directive:

```
uwsgi_param REMOTE_USER $remote_user;
uwsgi_param REMOTE_USER $ssl_client_s_dn_cn if_not_empty;
```

`$ssl_client_s_dn_cn` should override `$remote_user` if present. This approach has the advantage to use the two different variable names separately elsewhere (for example, the log format).

See:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_uwsgi_module.html#uwsgi_param

---

To use `$remote_user` as the default value for the `$ssl_client_s_dn_cn` variable when defining the `map`:

```
map $ssl_client_s_dn $ssl_client_s_dn_cn
{
    default $remote_user;
    ~/CN=(?<CN>[^/]+) $CN;
}
```

Please note that the `map` directive cannot be used at `server` context, while `location` should. And also note that Nginx variables cannot be overwritten.

Comment: But can I assume that $ssl_client_s_dn is simply not present (I assume by this you mean not defined) when the certificate validation fails?

Comment: In the first example, if it fails or even if it's a non-https request, it goes empty, then the directive `if_not_empty` prohibits it from being set at the REMOTE_USER uwsgi param. Note that it depends upon the `map` directive you stated above (otherwise, it wouldn't be set, and an error would be thrown).

In the second example, we use the `$remote_user` as the default value to the `$ssl_client_s_dn_cn`  variable, so you still need to set the `uwsgi_param REMOTE_USER $ssl_client_s_dn_cn;` line.

I'll update my answer to explain this through.

Answer (score 6):

Nginx 1.11 and 1.12 changed the quoting of $ssl_client_s_dn_cn.

If you come here and have headache, try this regexp instead:

```
map $ssl_client_s_dn $ssl_client_s_dn_cn {
        default "should_not_happen";
        ~CN=(?<CN>[^/,\"]+) $CN;
}
```